# RabbitMQ - Memory usage and message persistence

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I'm completely new to RabbitMQ and AMQP and I'm looking for a solution related to queues, message persistence and memory usage.

I'm trying to setting up a messaging system between a service and several clients. Said clients are basically people using an app on their phone so my first thought was to create:

- 1 *direct* exchange
- 1 *durable* queue + related binding **for each user**

This decision came up after reading that selective consumer pattern (1 queue, multiple consumers) seems to be a [bad practice](https://derickbailey.com/2015/07/22/airport-baggage-claims-selective-consumers-and-rabbitmq-anti-patterns/) in RabbitMQ.

However I found out that each queue created needs memory, and considering that I would need to declare thousands of queues (1 for each user), it would require a lot of memory so this is definitely not a solution for my case.

So I wonder would it be possible, for example, to keep a queue "disabled" while a user is offline and "enable" it once it comes online? This way I could achieve message persistence without keeping the queue active (ie. without consuming resources). Or is my approach completely wrong?

Comment: Do you need to preserve messages related to a particular user while he is offline?

Comment: Exactly @khoroshevj

Comment: Solution with queues doesn't look like the most optimal. Even if queues are “offline” or offloaded to disk for some time, there will be moments when many of these will be in RAM when many users are active. Consider storing messages in partitioned database, where partitions are so small so search for messages for a particular user would not take sensible amount of time.

Comment: Try Apache Kafka..

Answer (score 0):

I suppose rabbitmq.com/lazy-queues.html can be an option for you, it will consume significantly less RAM.

Second approach you can take is using https://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html to the exchange:

1. Add alternative exchange where all unrouted messages will go (messages for all offline users)
2. Consume all messages from this exchange and store somewhere (cache, db)
3. Remove user's queue right after he becomes offline,
4. After user becomes online send all previously collected messages and declare a new queue.

In that case you will keep queues just for online users, but you need to store somewhere all messages for offline users